# Running visual studio 2008 in current visual studio 2013

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-2013, pip, lxml

How, if possible, can I compile something using Visual Studio 2008 if I have Visual Studio 2013? I want to run `pip install lxml` and it gave me a `unable to find vcvarsall.bat` error. So I tried `SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS120COMNTOOLS%`. Then it gives me more errors and an exit status of 2. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using python2.7, microsoft recently published a special VC++ compiler for python:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and see how it goes.

Comment: I downloaded and installed and then tried pip install lxml but it still didn't work. Any ideas?